# Group of order $p^n$ has element of order $p$ without Cauchy's theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ be a group with $|G|=p^n$.
Show that G contains an element of order $p$.

I would immediately say: "use Cauchy's theorem!", but this question is from a course that hasn't introduced this yet. Is there another way to prove this?

It's clear that every element has an order $p^r$ for some $r\leq n$ because of Lagrange's theorem. How can we proceed?

Comment: Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by an element of order $p^{r}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $g \in G$, $g\ne 1$. Then the order of $g$ is $p^k$ and so the order of $g^{p^{k-1}}$ is $p$.

Comment: Don't you need Lagrange for the fact the "the order of $g$ is $p^k$"? And isn't Lagrange usually shown by making use of Cauchy?

Comment: @jpvee, yes, see the last sentence of the question.